# How can I create a wizard in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, code-generation

How can I write a wizard in Visual Studio/.NET to generate code and insert it in a form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this will be helpful a bit
[MSDN:Creating Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k3w6w59(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/default.aspx) for getting acquainted with VS Extensibility so you can create your own plugins.